# How to subtract the two values from a json data in python

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have a below json data:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "type": "POK",
            "value": "34"
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "type": "TOK",
            "value": "32"
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "type": "POC",
            "value": "43"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "type": "POK",
            "value": "45"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "type": "TOK",
            "value": "67"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "type": "POK",
            "value": "12"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "type": "POC",
            "value": "23"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "type": "TOK",
            "value": "34"
        },
        
    ]
}
```

In the above data, we can see that we have `id` as `1, 2, 3` with type being `POK` `TOK` `POC`. I have to write a script to subtract the value of each id having type as `POK` and `TOK`. For ex, id 1 with type `POK` subtracted from id 1 with type `TOK` so `34` - `32` to get answer `2`. Same goes for id 2 and 3.

For this I thought of first extracting the useful data from above json in a `dicts` of `list` and then subtracting each value like below:

```
import json


with open("data.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)


l = []
for i in range(len(data['data'])):
    d = dict()
    if data['data'][i]['type'] == 'POK':
        d['id'] = data['data'][i]['id']
        d['value'] = data['data'][i]['value']
        d['type'] = 'POK'
        l.append(d)
    if data['data'][i]['type'] == 'TOK':
        d['id'] = data['data'][i]['id']
        d['timestamp'] = data['value'][i]['value']
        d['type'] = 'TOK'
        l.append(d)
```

Now after above code I have a list `l` which has 6 `dict` in each which contains data

```
[
{'id': '1', 'value': '34', 'type': 'POK'}, 
{'id': '1', 'value': '32', 'type': 'TOK'}, 
{'id': '2', 'value': '45', 'type': 'POK'}, 
{'id': '2', 'value': '67', 'type': 'TOK'}, 
{'id': '3', 'value': '12', 'type': 'POK'}, 
{'id': '3', 'value': '34', 'type': 'TOK'}
]
```

After this I am not able to understand how do I subtract the values of each id having type `'POK'` and `'TOK'`. Can anyone give me some suggestions? Is there any other way of handling this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can use the built-in `all()` method:

```
dct = [{'id': '1', 'value': '34', 'type': 'POK'},
       {'id': '1', 'value': '32', 'type': 'TOK'},
       {'id': '2', 'value': '45', 'type': 'POK'},
       {'id': '2', 'value': '67', 'type': 'TOK'},
       {'id': '3', 'value': '12', 'type': 'POK'},
       {'id': '3', 'value': '34', 'type': 'TOK'}]

for d1 in dct:
    for d2 in dct:
        if all([d1['id'] == d2['id'], d1['type'] == 'POK' ,d2['type'] == 'TOK']):
            dct.append({'id': d1['id'], 'value': str(int(d1['value'])-int(d2['value'])), 'type': 'subtracted'})

print(dct)
```

Output:

```
[{'id': '1', 'value': '34', 'type': 'POK'},
 {'id': '1', 'value': '32', 'type': 'TOK'},
 {'id': '2', 'value': '45', 'type': 'POK'},
 {'id': '2', 'value': '67', 'type': 'TOK'},
 {'id': '3', 'value': '12', 'type': 'POK'},
 {'id': '3', 'value': '34', 'type': 'TOK'},
 {'id': '1', 'value': '2', 'type': 'subtracted'},
 {'id': '2', 'value': '-22', 'type': 'subtracted'},
 {'id': '3', 'value': '-22', 'type': 'subtracted'}]
```

Comment: Can you explain this line `if all(d1['id'] == d2['id'], d1['type'] == 'POK' ,d2['type'] == 'TOK'):`. This line is giving unexpected argument error

Comment: @SAndrew Sorry, `all()` need brackets in it. Fixed it. `all(lst)` returns `True` if all the booleans in the `lst` are true, else, it returns `False`.

Comment: @SAndrew The error you were running into is because all() takes an iterable rather than multiple arguments. Pass the arguments as a tuple or list (as per the edit that just went through) and it should work

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that using dictionaries would be the most intuitive way to organize the data for the subtractions. Here is an example as to how to achieve the desired operations and store them in a list:

```
list_of_dics = [
{'id': '1', 'value': '34', 'type': 'POK'}, 
{'id': '1', 'value': '32', 'type': 'TOK'}, 
{'id': '2', 'value': '45', 'type': 'POK'}, 
{'id': '2', 'value': '67', 'type': 'TOK'}, 
{'id': '3', 'value': '12', 'type': 'POK'}, 
{'id': '3', 'value': '34', 'type': 'TOK'}
]

TOKS = []
POKS = []
for entry in list_of_dics:
  if entry['type'] == 'TOK':
  ## We found a TOK store it for substraction
      TOKS.append((entry['id'], entry['value']))

  if entry['type'] == 'POK':
  ## We found a TOK store it for substraction
      POKS.append((entry['id'], entry['value']))

result = []

#I use this simple for loop since both lists should be of the same size as according to what you've shown on the answer.
for i in range(len(TOKS)):
  if TOKS[i][0] == POKS[i][0]:
  #We make the substractions since they have the same id
    result.append(int(POKS[i][1]) - int(TOKS[i][1]))

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your for loop is doing nothing but building same json object again.
Instead you can directly iterate over json and do the required calculation.
Working example:

```
import json

with open("data.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

result = {}
for d in data['data']:
    id = d['id']
    if d['type'] == 'POK':
        result[id] =  result.get(id, 0) + int(d['value'])
    if d['type'] == 'TOK':
        result[id] = result.get(id, 0) - int(d['value'])

print(result)
```

Output is

```
{'1': 2, '2': -22, '3': -22}
```

Comment: Can you explain the two `if` statements in your for loop?

Comment: If type is POK , for id, get value from result (default 0) and add value to it.  So for id 1 value will become 0 + 34 = 34. If type is TOK, for id, get value from result (default 0) and subtract current value. So for id 1 value will change 34 - 32 = 2.

Comment: Not able to understand. Why are you adding.?

Comment: To achieve X - Y , I am doing  0 + X - Y as by default dictionary is empty (I am initialising value to 0 at the same time).  So if order of your json changes .. still result will be same .. (X + Y) or (0 - Y + X) or (0 + X -Y) are all same